# Infinite while loop counting tokens Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to write a little program that counts the number of words in the string `words` and prints it to the console. But every time I run it, it's an infinite loop. What am I missing?

```
public static void main (String[] args){

  String words = "This is the sentence I want to use";

  Scanner s = new Scanner(words);
  int count = 0;

  while(s.hasNext()){
    count ++;
  }

  System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually parsing anything, you need to fetch tokens from the scanner through `next()` function:

```
while (s.hasNext())
{
  ++count;
  s.next();
}
```